# The method setAdUnitId(String) is undefined for the type InterstitialAd

Tags: java, android, eclipse, import

I was using the import: import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd.;
and the setADUnitId error had gone but the import gives me this error: The import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd collides with another import statement

```
 import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplication;
    import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidApplicationConfiguration;
    import com.google.ads.Ad;
    import com.google.ads.AdListener;
    import com.google.ads.AdRequest;
    import com.google.ads.AdRequest.ErrorCode;
    import com.google.ads.InterstitialAd;


    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
    import android.net.NetworkInfo;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Handler;
    import android.os.Message;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Window;
    import android.view.WindowManager;





    public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication implements
    AdListener {

        private ActionResolverAndroid actionResolverAndroid;
        private InterstitialAd interstitialAdMob;

        InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;




        @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            interstitialAdMob = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this,"null");
            mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.interstitial_full_screen)); //The method setAdUnitId(String) is undefined for the type InterstitialAd 
            interstitialAdMob.setAdListener(this);
            interstitialAdMob.loadAd(new AdRequest());
            requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
            getWindow().clearFlags(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

            AndroidApplicationConfiguration cfg = new AndroidApplicationConfiguration();
            cfg.useWakelock = true;
            cfg.useGL20 = false;

            actionResolverAndroid = new ActionResolverAndroid(this,
                    startAppInterHandler);
            View v = initializeForView(new JetPig(actionResolverAndroid), cfg);
            setContentView(v);
        }

        private boolean startAppExit;


            public Handler startAppInterHandler = new Handler() {

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                // if (startAppAd.isReady())
                //
                // {
                switch (msg.what) {
                case 1:
                    if (interstitialAdMob.isReady())
                    interstitialAdMob.show(); // show the ad
                    else
                    interstitialAdMob.loadAd(new AdRequest()); // load the next ad
                    break;
                case 2:
                    if (interstitialAdMob.isReady()) {
                        interstitialAdMob.show();
                        startAppExit = true;
                    } else
                        finish();

                default:
                    break;
                }
                Gdx.app.log("Add", "In ShowStartApp Hanlder");

                // }
            }
        };

        public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager
                    .getActiveNetworkInfo();
            return activeNetworkInfo != null;
        }

        public void finishActivity() {
            finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop() {
            super.onStop();
        }


        @Override
        public void onDismissScreen(Ad arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (startAppExit) {
                Gdx.app.log("Add", "Finsh");
                finish();
            }
            else
            {
                interstitialAdMob.loadAd(new AdRequest());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad arg0, ErrorCode arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onLeaveApplication(Ad arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onPresentScreen(Ad arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onReceiveAd(Ad arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you have already imported: `com.google.ads.InterstitialAd`, then now if you add the import: `com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd` then in your class will have 2 class with name `InterstitialAd` => this cause the collides. Let's go in to your code, you using `InterstitialAd` as follow: `private InterstitialAd interstitialAdMob;` => how can the compiler know you want to use what `InterstitialAd`? (because you have imported 2 class `InterstitialAd`). So that if this case you have to use both `com.google.ads.InterstitialAd` and `com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd` then the solution for you will be: import one and using the other one with full name.

For example:

```
import com.google.ads.InterstitialAd;
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication implements
    AdListener {
        //variable for class has imported
        private InterstitialAd interstitialAdMob;

        //variable for class has not imported
        private com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd interstitialAdMob_noImport;
        ...
}
```

EDIT: for your function `setADUnitId` it is only available in class [`com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/InterstitialAd) so please remove the other one.